Azure Logic App using Azure CLI and workflow definition isn't working
I am using the Azure CLI and using a workflow definition to create and run a Logic Apps workflow. The desired behavior of the Logic Apps is to store a copy of the file in Azure Blob whenever a new file is uploaded into the root directory of Dropbox. The Logic App with the workflow does get created; I confirmed this by checking in the Azure portal. However, the workflow is not functioning properly as whenever a new file is uploaded to dropbox, a copy of the file isn't being saved in Azure Blob.
workflow.json:
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@triggerBody()",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "RESOURCE_GROUP",
                            "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=RESOURCE_GROUP;AccountKey=SOME_ACCOUNT_KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('RESOURCE_GROUP'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/SOME_FOLDER",
                        "name": "@base64ToString(triggerOutputs()['x-ms-file-name-encoded'])",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_created": {
                "inputs": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "Raw",
                        "scheme": "Bearer",
                        "parameter": "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN"
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/onnewfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "6e202211-2856-4d17-9ded-5beb8b8626b0",
                        "inferContentType": true,
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "6e202211-2856-4d17-9ded-5beb8b8626b0": "/"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateless"
}

In terminal:
az logic workflow create --resource-group "intern-rg-dev" --name "dbx-trigger" --definition "workflow.json"

I've ran the command in the terminal to create a Logic App with the given workflow definition, but unfortunately, it isn't working, and I am having trouble figuring out why. I have read the documentation, which didn't help very much.

What is the error its showing. @gkim414


Azure Logic App using Azure CLI and workflow definition isn't working: -

Use below modified workflow definition code to achieve your requirement.
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_file_content": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "xxxx",
                            "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=RESOURCE_GROUP;AccountKey=SOME_ACCOUNT_KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent('/' & triggerBody()?['path'])}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Create_blob": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Get_file_content')",
                    "headers": {
                        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "xxxx"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "put",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent('CONTAINER_NAME/' & triggerBody()?['name'])}",
                    "queries": {
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_file_content": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_created": {
                "inputs": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "Raw",
                        "scheme": "Bearer",
                        "parameter": "ACCESS_TOKEN"
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/onnewfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "root", //Modify it as per your requirement
                        "inferContentType": true,
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "root": "/"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateless"
}

Complete command:
az logic workflow create --resource-group "xxxx" --name "dbx-trigger" --definition "workflow.json"

Output:

